# JSONP mimetype mismatch for instagram embed api

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

We are using JSONP approach to load instagram embed posts, however recently we got an issues with response content-type mime-type mismatch.
Any solutions to fix JSONP approach without switching to embed.js or to json?

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/BJPIEc8BHEI/&hidecaption=false&callback=_jsonp_instagramImage_0 with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

and IE:
The resource from ...  was blocked due to MIME type mismatch

Loading just by creating `<script>` and `callback`

Comment: content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
but it seems it is instagram bug and for JSONP(callback) it should be application/javascript content-type..

Answer (score 0):

Facebook say:

> This issue is related to the legacy Instagram API (api.instagram.com)
>   which isn't supported via this channel; this bug reporting tool only
>   supports issues related to the Instagram Graph API. Additionally, as
>   the legacy Instagram API has been deprecated as of July 2018, the team
>   is no longer accepted bug reports for this API. Thanks for your
>   understanding.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/235545030662906/

See also https://github.com/sugarshin/react-instagram-embed/issues/89.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue; it looks like Facebook changed their CORS policies a few days ago and didn't tell anybody. You'll have to work around CORS. I set up a php script to handle my GET request from my webapp, which in turn calls a python script to make the GET request and pass back the data. Happy to share the code if you'd like.